# Access C++ signals/slots globally in all QML files

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I want to access a C++ class (signals and slots) in all my qml files. When I set up a Connection in main.qml, I am able to receive the signal. However, in any other qml file (MainMenu.qml here), I can not access the signal. I can send from other qml files using slots functions, but not read the signals. Any idea how to fix it? I am very new to QML.

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Game game;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_game", &game);


    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));


    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
Window {
    id: root
    width: 1240
    height: 800
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Horse Race")
    color: "black"

    Image {
        id: backgroundImage
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "Imgs/Background.png"
    }

    Loader {
        id: mainLoader

        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            horizontalCenterOffset: - 100
        }

        source: "MainMenu.qml"
    }

    Connections {
        target: _game
        onNameUpdate: {
            console.log("updated name")
        }
        onStartedNewGame: {
            console.log("new game")
        }
    }
}
```

MainMenu.qml

```
Rectangle {
    Text {
        id: header
        anchors.horizontalCenter: root.horizontalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: + 35
        color: "white"
        font.family: "Super Mario Bros."
        font.pointSize: 30
        text: "Game Menu"
    }


    Connections {
        target: _game
        onStartedNewGame: {
            console.log("inside MainMenu")
            header.color = "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this should just work as is. I guess no warnings? Maybe you can try removing the underscore from the name?

Comment: Went ahead and tried your code, I have it reproduced as desired on Qt 5.12.5 (menu going blue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that I'm aware of.

1. The `Game` class is a `QObject`. Instead of instantiating it in your C++ code and calling `setContextProperty` on the `rootContext`, it's better to register `Game` instance as a QML `singleton` object. You will then have access to it wherever you import it. Here is an example (TestClass will be your Game class):

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class TestClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestClass(QQmlEngine* engine, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void triggerSignal() { emit aSignal(); } ;

private:

    QQmlEngine * m_engine;

signals:

   void aSignal();

public slots:

   void aSlot() { qDebug() << "aSlot invoked" };

};

static QObject *InstantiateTestClass(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
    TestClass *singletonClass = new TestClass(engine);
    return singletonClass;
}

static void registerTestClassSingleton()
{
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<TestClass>("Globals", 1, 0, "TestClass", InstantiateTestClass);
}

Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION(registerTestClassSingleton)
```

and in every QML file you can:

```
...
import Globals 1.0

Item {
...
    Connections {
        target: TestClass
        onASignal: {
            console.log("A Signal triggered")
        }
    }

}
```

Be aware that the `Game` class will be instantiated, when you refer to it for the first time. Creating a `Connection` won't invoke the `InstantiateTestClass` function. You should either call a function on TestClass, read a property or write a property to create the singleton instance. So, it's a good idea to create TestClass instance when the Window object is created like:

```
//main.qml
...
Windows{
...

Component.onCompleted: {
  //Just to create TestClass instance. You can also refer to a property instead of calling a method on it. 
  //Refering to a propery is enough for the TestClass to be instantiated.
  TestClass.aSlot();
}
}
```

2. You can also create a QML singleton type, create a `var` property in it and then set that `var` to `_game` in your `main.qml`. Then you will be able to access that member from every QML file. You should create a `qmldir` file beside that QML singleton file.

```
//GameHelper.qml

pragma Singleton
...

QtObject{
   property var gameInstance
}
```

```
//main.qml
...
import "."

Window{
...

Component.onCompleted: {
  GameHelper.gameInstance = _game;
}

}
```

```
//MainMenu.qml
...
Item{

    Connections {
        target: GameHelper.gameInstance
        onASignal: {
            console.log("A Signal triggered")
        }
    }

}
```

Both methods will work. I will prefer the first one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm going to try it. Would I have to do anything special in main.cpp, for example with engines?

Comment: @sjokkopudd No. You will need to remove ```Game``` instantiation from your main.cpp. If you look carefully at the ```TestClass``` you will see a macro called ```Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION```. This will call the ```registerTestClassSingleton``` right when ```QCoreApplication``` is created and it will register the ```TestClass``` QML type. This will save your main.cpp from being polluted by many QML type registration and makes your class more portable.

Comment: Do I still need the QObject::connect()?

Comment: @sjokkopudd yes, you do. It's related to loading the main.qml. It doesn't have anything to do with the ```Game``` class.